# Preserve scroll position when navigating back/forward in Safari?

Tags: safari, macos

It seems we've been spoiled by other browsers, but sometimes you just can't use them (like for viewing Apple videos).

When I hit back/forward in Safari, then immediately I lose my place on the page. Is there an option to make Safari remember your page scroll position like every other browser?

Comment: It does it with me. What versions of the OS and Safari are you using?

Comment: Can you give some example websites where you're observing this? And what is your Safari version? This is the type of feature that Apple would just make work, without providing an option.

Comment: Sorry, after investigating it seems I'm thinking of xcode's internal browser. Heh. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you're running into the "continuous scrolling" nightmare, which has become popular in recent times.

On all "regular" websites, this is not an issue from Safari 6+ and since at least Lion.

The problem is that some websites load a page, then when you reach the bottom of that page, it loads the next page below the current one. This is meant to be useful, but in the majority of cases it breaks navigation, since the page reloads on navigation.

There is no solution to this mess, other than to disable continuous scrolling, if the webpage you're accessing gives you that option.